# Migrate kubeflow docker image components to VertexAI pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines, vertex-ai-pipeline

I am trying to migrate a custom component created in kubeflow to VertexAI.
In Kubeflow I used to create components as docker container images and then load them into my pipeline as follows:

```
def my_custom_component_op(gcs_dataset_path: str, some_param: str):
    return kfp.dsl.ContainerOp(
        name='My Custom Component Step',
        image='gcr.io/my-project-23r2/my-custom-component:latest',
        arguments=["--gcs_dataset_path", gcs_dataset_path,
                   '--component_param', some_param],
        file_outputs={
            'output': '/app/output.csv',
        }
    )
```

I would then use them in the pipeline as follows:

```
@kfp.dsl.pipeline(
    name='My custom pipeline',
    description='The custom pipeline'
)
def generic_pipeline(project_id, some_param):
    
    output_component = my_custom_component_op(
        gcs_dataset_path=gcs_dataset_path,
        some_param=some_param
    )

    output_next_op = next_op(gcs_dataset_path=dsl.InputArgumentPath(
        output_component.outputs['output']),
        next_op_param="some other param"
    )
```

Can I reuse the same component docker image from kubeflow v1 in vertex ai pipeline? How can I do that? hopefully without changing anything in the component itself.

I have found examples online of vertex AI pipelines that uses the `@component` decorator as follows:

```
@component(base_image=PYTHON37, packages_to_install=[PANDAS])
def my_component_op(
    gcs_dataset_path: str,
    some_param: str
    dataset: Output[Dataset],
):
   ...perform some op....
```

But this would require me to copy paste the docker code in my pipeline and this is not really something I want to do. Is there a way to re-use the docker image and passing the parameters? I couldn't find any example of that anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prepare component yaml and load it with [load_component_from_file](https://kubeflow-pipelines.readthedocs.io/en/stable/source/hkfp.components.html#kfp.components.load_component_from_file).

It's well documented on kfp v2 Kubeflow documentation [page](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v1/sdk-v2/component-development/), it's also written [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/main/notebooks/official/pipelines/pipelines_intro_kfp.ipynb).